# Phonegap device on/offline

Tags: cordova, device, offline

I'm trying to send my app to an error page if there is no internet connection. I've installed the relevant plugins and added the code below.

I can detect for the type of connection and if the device is offline alert a message.

I'm struggling to send the app to an error page if offline and back to the home page when the device is back online.

```
// device APIs are available
//
function onDeviceReady() {
    document.addEventListener("offline", app.onOffline, false);
},

// Handle the offline event
//
onOffline: function() {
     alert("off line");
},

checkConnection: function() {
    var networkState = navigator.connection.type;

    var states = {};
    states[Connection.UNKNOWN]  = 'Unknown connection';
    states[Connection.ETHERNET] = 'Ethernet connection';
    states[Connection.WIFI]     = 'WiFi connection';
    states[Connection.CELL_2G]  = 'Cell 2G connection';
    states[Connection.CELL_3G]  = 'Cell 3G connection';
    states[Connection.CELL_4G]  = 'Cell 4G connection';
    states[Connection.CELL]     = 'Cell generic connection';
    states[Connection.NONE]     = 'No network connection';

    alert('Connection type: ' + states[networkState]);
},
```

Could someone please point me in the right direction.

Cheers

Wayne.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks for the help, I redirected when device is offline using the offline EventListener to call the function.

```
checkState: function(){
    window.location.href = "offline.html";
},
```

Answer (score 0):

Add another event listener:

```
document.addEventListener("online", app.onOnline, false);
```

AND

```
onOnline: function() {
     alert("on line");
},
```

This listener is only fired when your app is already loaded and gains a connection -- either you started w/o a connection and then gained a connection, or you lost connection after the app loaded and then regained connection.

I use the devices `airplane mode` to test this listener.

Comment: Thanks, do you how I would go about sending the user to a page when there is no connection?

Answer (score 0):

try this one

```
document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);
// device APIs are available
//
function onDeviceReady() {
    checkConnection();
}

function checkConnection() {
    var networkState = navigator.connection.type;
    var states = {};
    states[Connection.UNKNOWN] = 'Unknown connection';
    states[Connection.ETHERNET] = 'Ethernet connection';
    states[Connection.WIFI] = 'WiFi connection';
    states[Connection.CELL_2G] = 'Cell 2G connection';
    states[Connection.CELL_3G] = 'Cell 3G connection';
    states[Connection.CELL_4G] = 'Cell 4G connection';
    states[Connection.CELL] = 'Cell generic connection';
    states[Connection.NONE] = 'No network connection';
    if ((states[networkState]) == states[Connection.NONE]) {
        alert('No Internet Connection. Click OK to exit app');
        navigator.app.exitApp();
    }
}
```

Make sure you add these plugins first.

- https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-network-information
- https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-device